# gdb seems to be running lines of code twice while not in a loop

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, mariadb-connector-c

I'm thoroughly confused by gdb while debugging my code. The debugger seems to step over two lines of my code twice for no reason. Is this something my code has caused?

the output of gdb is pretty self explanatory. I did try removing the initialization and connect code out to just a main function and when compiled gdb works as expected and doesn't seem to loop like it does when I call the same code inside a separate function.

mariadb_helper.c

```
#include "mariadb_helper.h"

void finish_w_error(MYSQL *con) {

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
}

MYSQL *connect_db(const char *host, const char *user, const char *passwd, const char *db) {

        MYSQL *c = mysql_init(NULL);

        if(c == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(c));
                exit(1);
        }

        if(mysql_real_connect(c, host, user, passwd, NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
                finish_w_error(c);
        }

        return c;
}
```

db.c

```
#include "mariadb_helper.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        MYSQL *con = connect_db("localhost", "db", "68qrr*", NULL);

        if(con == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
                exit(1);
        }

        mysql_close(con);
        return 0;
}
```

gdb output - notice how lines 14 and 16 seem to called twice? What is causing this?

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006c0: file db.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jasin/dev/c/mariadb/db
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffffffee688) at db.c:7
7       int main(int argc, char **argv) {
(gdb) n
9               MYSQL *con = connect_db("localhost", "db", "68qrr*", NULL);
(gdb) s
connect_db (host=host@entry=0x40097e "localhost", user=user@entry=0x40097b "db",
    passwd=passwd@entry=0x400974 "68qrr*", db=db@entry=0x0) at mariadb_helper.c:14
14      MYSQL *connect_db(const char *host, const char *user, const char *passwd, const char *db) {
(gdb) n
16              MYSQL *c = mysql_init(NULL);
(gdb) n
14      MYSQL *connect_db(const char *host, const char *user, const char *passwd, const char *db) {
(gdb) n
16              MYSQL *c = mysql_init(NULL);
(gdb) n
18              if(c == NULL) {
(gdb)
```

I would expect the debugger to step through the code line by line and not loop back to the calling function and repeat line 16 twice. My question is why is this happening and is it harmful? Something I can change? inefficient? It just doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: are you by chance debugging optimized code?

Comment: how would I know? `gcc -o db db.c mariadb_helper.c  `mariadb_config --cflags --libs`` is the command I use to compile. I am using the libmariadb-dev  and this call does use that lib, but as stated if I do the same code inside of main() it works as expected.

Comment: check compiler options. Optimizer flags should be off when you want to debug. Please post your makefile or build line execution trace

Comment: `gcc -o db db.c mariadb_helper.c  'mariadb_config --cflags --libs'` but adding in -Og didn't seem to change anything.